# Is there a standardized metadata attribute for describing which classification system is used for a (string) variable?

Tags: netcdf, cf-metadata

Suppose I have a variable that is a classification of something. In this example, it is a classification of soil texture:

```
String soil_class(depth=3);
  :string system = "USC";

data = "Organic clays", "Silty gravels", "Silty gravels",
```

Are there existing standards (CF or otherwise) that describe the name that should be given to an attribute that provides the classification system that is used (in this example, I use the attribute name `system`)?.

There are similar applications for metadata (instead of data from a variable) where a secondary attribute indicates the vocabulary or classification system used for the primary metadata attribute:

- In the [IOOS standard](https://ioos.github.io/ioos-metadata/ioos-metadata-profile-v1-2.html) `contributor_role_vocabulary` is used for `contributor_role`
- In the [ACDD standard](https://wiki.esipfed.org/Attribute_Convention_for_Data_Discovery_1-3) `standard_name_vocabulary` is used for `standard_name`

but to reiterate, these refer back to metadata attributes, not data. I am unaware of any convention that provides a "classification_vocabulary" equivalent for classified data, but want to be sure before I make an ad-hoc one.